Standard Visa Validity for F1?
So when trying to schedule an interview at the US embassy, I get the question whether I want to apply for a visa with standard validity (19 months) or a 4 year visa. According to my I-20, the length of my program is 196 weeks. Which option should I pick? If the latter, I'm also told to write on my DS-160 confirmation page that I'd like a 4 year visa - which I don't understand how I can even do (there's not field for that on the confirmation page). Is there any advantage to picking the 4 year option?

Visa validity depends on the country of residence/nationality and you don't really get a say in that. Where did you see such a question?

On the page used to book the visa interview (found it through the embassy's webpage). There's a questionnaire in which one of the questions is whether I want to apply for a 4 year visa or 19 month visa (standard visa validity).

What embassy? Where are you applying?
